# Install RVM itself without internet connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am switching from DJANGO to Rails, but i don't know how to install RVM in PROD environment.

My PROD server is without internet connection, and not possible connect even for a while. And i cannot find a standalone install package of RVM.

Is there any solution for offline RVM installation?

BTW, can rails be installed without internet?

Comment: so the server can only serve traffic on one port and can not access anything outside? Or it's your home machine with no network? What system is this?

Comment: The server are not allowed to connect because its for internal use only in my company. The only thing i can do is copy files via USB disc. And the os is Centos6.2. @mpapis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just spent some time and build a tutorial for the offline mode: https://rvm.io/rvm/offline - it's the first version so feel free to improve it here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-site/blob/master/content/rvm/offline.md (Edit button).

Comment: That it is. I'm trying this and will refer to you later if any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to my first answer another way to do it would be to compile ruby on **online** machine, then package it, unpack on the other end and add it to PATH on the **offline** machine.

### Way 1 - only Ruby

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm install 1.9.3 --movable
rvm prepare 1.9.3
```

Some information will be displayed, including file name. Copy it to the offline machine and unpack it there, then just add it to `PATH`:

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:${unpacked_dir}/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

### Way 2 - whole RVM:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm use 1.9.3 --install
gem install rails -v 3.2.8
rails new rails3
rvm use 1.8.7 --install
gem install rails -v 2.3.14
rails new rails2
tar czf rvm_and_ruby.tgz /usr/local/rvm /etc/rvmrc /profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Unpack on the offline end:

```
cd /
sudo tar xzf rvm_and_ruby.tgz
```

And open a new terminal.

Answer (score 0):

check http://railsinstaller.org/ (for windows and mac) .After then change environment into production mode . In linux this works `export RAILS_ENV=production` .

Comment: railsinstaller seems not working in Centos. =.= Is any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linux OS, you can always package the app as a debian or rpm archive which will include rails and the dependent gems referred in your Gemfile.  The advantage with this approach is that you can also configure the archive to setup external dependencies like any other deb or rpm package.  One of my recent projects came up with a in house solution. Now there are tools like [pkgr](http://crohr.me/pkgr/)

Comment: As my understand, pkgr is another way to deploy rails apps. But now my question is about install environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a standalone RVM package here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/tags

You can reference the [RVM installer script](https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer) for details on what an RVM install does. Simply replace the network calls with references to some local file, and you should be good to go.

That said, once RVM is installed, I'm not sure if it'll let you do an offline Ruby install easily, but this should get you started.

Comment: the script download source from git. So do i have to setup a fake rvm git instead?

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that it's donwloading one of those tarballs I linked. :)

Answer (score -1):

Well you need to download the source code from somewhere to install RVM, Rails.  Not very clear as to how your Prod environment lacks an internet connection.  Could you please give more details?

Comment: The server are not allowed to connect because its for internal use only in my company. The only thing i can do is copy files via USB disc. And the os is Centos6.2.